# getting incompatible types when using .length method

Tags: java

I am working on an exercises from Objects first with java for self review. The part of the exercises that I am having trouble with is where it asks me to find the length of the refNumber string..if the length of the string is zero, then print out a line saying "zzz". I have tried doing this by making a local variable, and making it equal to refNumber.length(). However in my conditional statement bluejay indicates that I have an incompatible type. Ugh, please help. Thanks in advance.

```
class Book
{
// The fields.
private String author;
private String title;
private int pages;
private String refNumber;

/**
 * Set the author and title fields when this object
 * is constructed.
 */
public Book(String bookAuthor, String bookTitle, int numberOfPages)
{
    author = bookAuthor;
    title = bookTitle;
    numberOfPages = pages;
    refNumber = "";
}

public String getAuthor()
{
    return author;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public int getPages()
{
    return pages;
}

public String getRefNumber()
{
    return refNumber;
}

public void setRefNumber(String ref){
    ref = refNumber;
}

public void printTitle() {
    System.out.println("Book desciption: " + title);

}

public void printAuthor() {
    System.out.print(" by " + author);

}

public void printPages(){
    System.out.println("Pages: " + pages);
}

public void printRef(){
    int count = refNumber.length();
    if (count = 0){                        //incompatible type wtf?
    System.out.println("zzz");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Reference Number: " + referenceNumber);
    }

}
```

Comment: don't you think you should have `==` for comparison in `if` statement?

Answer (score 2):

Most programming languages use the single equals sign `=` to be an assignment operator. What you are trying to do is compare the two numbers, which uses the double equal sign `==`.

So, effectively, your code is trying to assign count with the value `0`, then check if the value is `true` or `false`. And since the result of an assignment operation is neither `true` nor `false`, it throws the error.

As other people are saying, use `count == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

try it ..get out put

```
 if (refNumber.length() == 0){                        
    System.out.println("zzz");
    }
```

Comment: care to explain why. What was the error and benefits of using this.

Comment: @ Harry Joy == is usefull to him

Comment: Yeah I know. But why its useful? Explain it in your answer. Don't just paste code, add some explanation on why and how to use the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if (count == 0){ 
    ....
}
```

'=' is assignment operator and '==' is comparison operator

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if(count == 0)
```

In your code it's like you are assigning 0 to count which cannot happen in the if clause, since it expects a boolean based on the condition. So here you should check if count is equals (using equality operator == ) and in return it returns true if they are equal or false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`count=0` stands for assignment while `count==0` stands for comparison.